# Sublime fails to open new_file in macro

Tags: macros, sublimetext3

In Sublime (Version 3.2.2, Build 3211) (Ubuntu 18.04.5), I'd like to record a macro where I select-all, copy and paste the current content into another, unsaved file. And then do other commands as well, but I'm not even getting that far. The new-file step doesn't seem to work – neither `new`, nor `new_window`, `newWindow`, `new_file`, `newFile` seem to work; not even `reopen_last_file`. It [should be](https://docs.sublimetext.io/reference/commands.html#commands) `new_file`, though.

The console throws this:

```
Unknown macro command new_file
```

Which is weird. The command `new_file` works fine in other contexts: looking at the key-bindings settings, `ctrl+n` is bound to the same command and the hotkey has no issues.

Selecting all, copying – even this following bit works as intended:

```
{
    "command": "insert",
    "args": {"characters": "Hello, Friend!\n"}
}
```

In their forums, user "jps" [writes](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sublime-text-x-20101108/1010/7):

> With regards to the other console messages (unknown command, etc), don’t worry about them, they’re supposed to be there :slight_smile:

… but this doesn't seem to be right if it's obviously not working.

I have a project open but closing the project has no effect.

Is there maybe a package or something missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros in sublime can only capture and replay `TextCommand` commands; that is, commands that directly modify the content of a buffer or it's visual state. Examples including adding or removing text, changing the selection, moving the cursor around or changing `view` specific settings (like toggling word wrap or changing rulers, etc).

Commands like `new_file`, `new_window` or opening and closing projects are `WindowCommand` commands, which can't be captured via a macro.

In order to run a sequence of commands that includes a `WindowCommand` (or `ApplicationCommand`), you need to use a package. Two examples of that which are readily available on Package Control are [Chain of Command](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Chain%20of%20Command) and [Multicommand](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Multicommand).

Comment: Hm, yup you're right. I just [found it](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/extensibility/macros.html#how-to-record-macros): `Also, macros only record commands sent to the buffer: window-level commands, such creating a new file, will be ignored.` (that part should have been bold or indented or something). I ended up doing the copy-pasta part manually and then using RegReplace for the subsequent steps. Thanks, anyway.